# Could not find `Options` in `getopts`

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the `Options` struct in the `getopts` crate, which exists according to the Rust book.

The code I am running is this.

```
let mut opts = getopts::Options::new();
```

While building the project the compiler gives the error

> ```
>  let mut opts = getopts::Options::new();
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Could not find `Options in `getopts`
> ```

How do I resolve this? I am using the **nightly** version of Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [crates.io version](https://crates.io/crates/getopts) instead.  You can see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/getopts/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L102-L104) that the built-in version of `getopts` has been flagged as a compiler internal with `rustc_private`.  The version on crates.io is basically the same crate.  The compiler-internal version is just kept segregated for various reasons.

Comment: It worked! I added  this to my Cargo.toml.

`[dependencies]
getopts = "0.2.14" `